# Why doesn't U-Net work with images different from the dataset?

Tags: datasets, image-segmentation, u-net, training-datasets, test-datasets

I have implemented a U-Net, similar to [this implementation](https://github.com/bnsreenu/python_for_microscopists/blob/master/076-077-078-Unet_nuclei_tutorial.py), but for a different dataset, [this one](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Evmnih/data/), to segment roads.

It works fine using the test folder images, but, for example, when I pick a print from bing maps and try to infer with the trained model, this is returned:

[image]

Why this is happening?

I already tried to change the thresholding values, normalization, etc.

[Tensorboard](https://tensorboard.dev/experiment/voY25RDaQ4yKSEDWrlhqEg/)

Comment: One thing to check - image could be with value range in [0, 255] and [0, 1]. Make sure this range is identical for train and test images)

Comment: When you say in the title "with images different from the dataset", you mean "test dataset", right? It may be a good idea to show us an example of an image from the test dataset too (even though you already provide a link to the dataset).